# Grails / Angular / Gradle: posssible resource-loading issue with grails-gradle-plugin?

Tags: grails, gradle, dependencies

Grails / Angular / Gradle: posssible resource-loading issue with gradle-grails-plugin?

I have a **Grails** project (project named web-grails) with an **Angular** frontend. What we want to do is to refactor out the Angular components - mainly the JavaScript (js) and HTML files - into its own project (named web-js-html), i.e. have a separate JavaScript/HTML project bundled up into a jar.

We're using **Gradle** to build those 2 projects in a  multi-build. web-js-html is assembled so that all the resources are under *META-INF/resources*. This way, the servlet 3.0 container will automatically put them onto the classpath, i.e. we can just reference them in web-grails' HTML files for example. Something like

```
// file: web-grails/grails-app/views/index.gsp
<html>
    <body>
    ...
    <script src="webjars/gradle-multiproject/components/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

then works as the referenced jquery file was found on the classpath from the referenced web-js-html project.

When I deploy the web-grails' war in a standalone Tomcat 7.0.54, everything works fine, i.e. the referenced JavaScript files are loaded and the page loads accordingly.
However, when I run web-grails directly from gradle, using

> gradle grails-run-app

the referenced files from the web-js-html project cannot be found / loaded (we receive a 404), for example:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/web-grails/webjars/gradle-multiproject/components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Our configs for Gradle are as follows:

```
// web-grails/build.gradle

apply plugin: "grails"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url artifactory_url }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url artifactory_url }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'
    }
}

grails {
    grailsVersion = '2.3.8'
    groovyVersion = '2.3.0'
}

dependencies {
    bootstrap 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.50'
    compile "com.h2database:h2:1.3.173"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.7"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.13"
    compile project(':web-js-html')
}


// web-js-html/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

ext {
    webjarconfig = [
            staticHTMLFilesDir : "${projectDir}/src/main/webfrontend",
            baseDir: "META-INF/resources/",
            subDir : "webjars/" + deployed_app_name
    ]
}

jar {
    from(fileTree(webjarconfig.staticHTMLFilesDir)) {
        into webjarconfig.baseDir + webjarconfig.subDir
    }
    outputs.file archivePath
}
```

I'm unsure how to proceed. The source code of grails-gradle-plugin suggests that the necessary dependencies are put onto the classpath which is confirmed when I deploy the war file in a standalone Tomcat (as stated above).

Is this a configuration problem on my side, i.e. am I not using the plugin the right way? Or could this be an issue / bug in the plugin? I didn't find there to be an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/issues

Any ideas?